# Alert when app don't have internet connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I have an application which needs an internet connection in UiWebView and I want to show a little alert when application doesn't have an internet connection.  I tried

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {


    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Message!" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *ok =  [UIAlertAction
                          actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                          style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                          handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                          {
                              [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                          }];


    [alert addAction:ok];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

but this didn't work for me.  When I start the application without an internet connection it crashes every time.  Any ideas?  Thank you for help!

Comment: Do your get any error messages? In the logs? Stack dump?

Comment: Nothing :( Application crashing when I don't enable internet connection but if I have connection it work correctly

Answer (score 0):

import Reachability.h and use this code

```
 if ([[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection]currentReachabilityStatus]==NotReachable)
        {
             //connection unavailable
        }
        else
        {
             //connection available
        }
```

and here is link from where you can download it.

https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability

Comment: It works when I have internet but if I set off connection I have `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initWithString:relativeToURL:]: nil string parameter'`

Comment: Put if(relativeToURL){
}
else
{
}